# why logger disappears after configuration?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

using `logging.config.dictConfig()` seems to remove or disable the loggers that are not in the configuration. this is confusing to me.

here's a question for the minimal example below:

> why does the output from logger1 not shown after the configuration?
>   should it not just propagate to the root logger just it does for logger2?

example:

```py
import logging
import logging.config
import yaml

logger1 = logging.getLogger('logger1')
logger2 = logging.getLogger('logger2')

logger1.error('logger1: this is shown 1')
logger2.error('logger2: this is shown 2')

config_string = """
version: 1
loggers:
  logger2:
      level: ERROR
"""

config_dict = yaml.safe_load(config_string)
logging.config.dictConfig(config_dict)

logger1.error('logger1: why is this not shown 3')
logger2.error('logger2: this is shown 4')
```

actual output:

```
logger1: this is shown 1
logger2: this is shown 2
logger2: this is shown 4
```

the output I expected:

```
logger1: this is shown 1
logger2: this is shown 2
logger1: why is this not shown 3
logger2: this is shown 4
```

Answer (score 0):

found it.

it turns out, we need to add `disable_existing_loggers: False` inside the dict, like so

```
config_string = """
version: 1
disable_existing_loggers: False
loggers:
  logger2:
      level: ERROR
"""
```

this fixes the issue